# Cannot assign a role for a Customer Community User

Tags: customer-community, community, roles, customer-community-plus

I understand that Community Roles are being created once you create the first user for that specific account. However, when trying to assign the Role, the dropdown is empty.

So, what I already validated is to check if the Account Owner and the Contact Owner had a role assigned which they do. I don't think it has to do but was just a validation.

I also renamed the community default roles for custom in the community administration to see if that enabled the role but not luck.

Finally I validated the Sharing settings and the checkbox Community User Visibility is disabled which is what I need.

What I'm missing? It was my understanding that those roles were created automatically by salesforce once you create the first user for that account.

Comment: Did you follow the documentation? if so which one, what steps did you do. Please link any related doc that you might have used so others can help you. Include screenshots when possible as well and refer to [ask] if any of this is unclear.

Comment: here is a link from salesforce's doc, did you follow every step? https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_create_external_users.htm&language=en_US&type=0

Comment: Thanks @crmprogdev, I did follow up the documentation. I apologize to not include a screenshot, I thought it was not necessary... Nevertheless I believe the issue is the license as your noted in your answer below. Let me validate and if it is the issue it will be marked as accepted answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds as though you must have a Customer Community Plus license. Regular Customer Communities do not use Roles, instead they only use Profiles. You could say they "quasi-inherit" their Role from their Owner.

If you are using a Community Plus license, for best performance, you really only want to use 1 single role per account throughout your community and not create multiple roles for every account (up to 3). See [Set the Default Number of Community Roles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_default_roles.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=206.20) in the Help for more on this.

There's also an option to automatically use the User's Account Name for their Role by enabling "Show Company Name as Community Role" in Community Management under Member Administration. See [Set Custom Community Roles](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_custom_community_role.htm&type=0&language=en_US&release=206.20) in the Help for more details.

**EDIT 01/22/2022**

To actually get one role for an entire Experience Cloud Portal that uses the Community Plus license, you need to first enable a feature called [Account Role Optimization](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_partners_optimize_roles.htm&language=en_US&type=5) (ARO). If you read the documentation you'll see this solution is intended only for users created as person accounts and isn't for users with Partner Licenses.

Be aware using ARO has a significant impact on role based sharing rules which you'll want to carefully consider before implementing it. In an existing portal, you'd also need to update each user via apex using code along the lines of the following:

```
User u = new User();
u.Id = '<user id>';
u.PortalRole = 'PersonAccount';
update u;
```

Comment: Confirmed. The issue is the Community License. I need a Plus license to have roles. These were the links that clarified for me: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=users_license_types_communities.htm&language=en_US&type=0 and https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000206085&type=1

Comment: Glad you got the cause or your issue sorted out. If this post led you to solving your issue, please help the rest of the community by marking it as having answered your question.

Comment: Done, sorry I thought I did that when I confirmed. Thanks again.

Comment: @crmprogdev how do you make it just create ONE role for the whole community? the links you referenced talk about 1 role PER ACCOUNT

Comment: @zaitsman That's correct. In a Partner or Community Plus Experience, each account gets at least one Role. It's not possible declaratively to apply One role to all users from different accounts but you can enable (account role optimization)(https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_partners_optimize_roles.htm&language=en_US&type=5) and do it with code. See edited answer above.

Comment: @crmprogdev ARO simply means `only create 1 role if you have 1 user per-account` which is better than the default 3 but still shit. Even with your Apex code the roles will still be created, they just won't be used.

Comment: @zaitsman ARO is only one part of the solution I was attempting to allude to. See Optimize Account Roles to Improve Performance and Scale at https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.networks_partners_optimize_roles.htm&type=5.

Comment: @crmprogdev I read that article many times over the years. It literally says `When a second user with a role-based license is added to the account, more roles are necessary to support sharing data`. There is literally no way to have tens of external users under accounts and have ALL external users in the org in ALL accounts share the same role.

Comment: @zaitsman If you read the article on ARO, you'll discover that declarative role based sharing rules are disabled when ARO is enabled.

Comment: @crmprogdev and that's relevant how exactly? :) I am trying to achieve a scenario where I have ONE role for all my external customer users regardless of accounts. I do not use sharing rules at all. It seems impossible because as soon as account has more than user more roles are created.